# Getting AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isnumeric' error

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror

---

Here I'am trying to build a simple calculator using tkinter and I have used some number images as buttons,i want only numbers and mathematical characters to be entered in entry box,but when i press the number button i get **AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'** error, I didn't get the solution for this problem:
here is my code and below code is function for tkinter button:

```
def press(n):
    new=value.get()
    if new=="Can't divide by zero" or new=="Can't perform operation":
        new=''
    if n.isnumeric() or n=='+' or n=='-' or n=='*' or n=='/' or n=='%' or n=='.':
        new+=str(n)
        value.set(new)
```

Comment: Where does `n` come from? The error is telling you that `n` is not a string. [`isnumeric()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) is a string method.

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The python `isnumeric()` method expects a string and checks if the characters in the string are numeric. If you're already passing n into `def press(n)` as an integer there is no reason to check if it's numeric and it's expecting a string which is why you get the `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'`. Your input should be a string, not an int literal.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> The python isnumeric() method expects a string and checks if the characters in the string are numeric
> ```

as bpiekars said, and you can try:

```
str(n).isnumeric()
```